# Sending a form in the modal window

Tags: php, jquery

sorry that I start this topic. I know that there were a lot of topics in this matter. But still I can not deal with it, because I need the success / failure messages to be displayed as below:

```
<!-- Form in modal -->
<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['error_msg'])){echo $_SESSION['error_msg']; unset($_SESSION['error_msg']);}?>
<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['success_msg'])){echo $_SESSION['success_msg']; unset($_SESSION['success_msg']);}?>
<form id="test-form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="submit" name="save-test-form" value="Save">
</form>
```

---

```
/* test.php */
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['save-test-form'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
            $_SESSION['success_msg'] = 'All is well.';
        }else{
            $_SESSION['error_msg'] = 'Enter the email.';
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['error_msg'] = 'Enter the name.';
    }
}
?>
```

---

```
And jquery?
```

My point is to submit this form without reloading the page (because it's in the modal window) and I have to display success / failure messages in the form (also without reloading the page). I do not know how to do it.

I will be grateful for the help and explanation of how to do it step by step.

Comment: I don't know what exactly is your problem. But I see you have a typing mistake `$_SESSION['succes_msg']` != `$_SESSION['success_msg']`

Comment: Sorry, I just gave you an example of code here. I have a different script. My point is to submit this form without reloading the page (because it's in the modal window) and I have to display success / failure messages in the form (also without reloading the page). I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Try AJAX, there are some good tutorials

Comment: Your PHP is executed only on reload of page, when using Ajax you have to manually set display of error messages that you get as response from server.

Comment: Justinas, Could you write a sample code for me with these messages? Please. I do not know javascript well. And I need this solution. I have been struggling with this for a few days :(

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script is executed on page reload, so when using Ajax you must manually show messages from server:

```
// PHP

$response = [];

if(isset($_POST['save-test-form'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
        if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
            $response['success'] = 'All is well.';
        }else{
            $response['error_msg'] = 'Enter the email.';
        }
    }else{
        $response['error_msg'] = 'Enter the name.';
    }

    echo json_encode($response); // Format array as json and output it
    die(); // No other output, just JSON
}

// jQuery

$.ajax({
    url: '',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: function (response) {
        if (typeof response.success !== 'undefined') {
            $('#responseMessage').text(response.success);
        } else {
            $('#responseMessage').text(response.error_msg);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I think I'm slowly beginning to understand. Thanks. Just one more question - Does not the jquery script need to somehow be initialized to run only after clicking the submit button in the form?

Comment: @LukaszStaszewski Yes, it does. But this part is not included in question or in my answer. Google `jQuery form hijacking`